# Need help manually setting breaks using the cut command in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset in which I want to categorize numeric values into groups.
In this case I want to have cut breaks that categorize the values into groups all starting with 0 such as 0-5, 0-10, 0-15 etc...

So essentially i'm trying to aggregate the observations manually.

Is there a way to tell the cut function to do this?
Sorry if this is unclear, thanks in advance

Comment: But, if you have a value of "4", does it go in the "0-5", "0-10", or "0-15" group? What about a value of "9"?

Comment: Sorry I phrased this poorly. In the case of 4 I would want it to go into all 3 groups, in the case of 9 I would want it to go into both the 0-10 and the 0-15 group

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create multiple groups with specific ranges, where each value may be part of any number of groups (4 would be part of 0-5, 0-10, and 0-15).

If you want to do this, just create new columns for each group and conditionally set them to `1` or `TRUE` or whatever value you want to indicate the group membesrship with:

```
df = data.frame(value=as.integer(runif(20,0,20)))
df[,c("g5","g10","g15","g20")] = FALSE
df$g5[df$value<=5]=T
df$g10[df$value<=10]=T
df$g15[df$value<=15]=T
df$g20[df$value<=20]=T
```

This will give you the dataframe:

```
> df
   value    g5   g10   g15  g20
1     15 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
2     15 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
3      9 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
4      8 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
5     13 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
6     10 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
7      7 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
8      2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
9      6 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
10     5  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
11    13 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
12    14 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
13    14 FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
14    16 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
15     1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
16    19 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
17     4  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
18     3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
19    17 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
20    10 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
```

If you need more groups, you could, of course, do it with a for-loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer the question, that was exactly what I needed